# Google maps infowindow scrolling bug: How to solve for all cases?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

It's a [known bug](https://www.google.es/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=bug%20infowindow%20scrollbar) that the Google Maps API shows the scrollbar for the first (time) clicked infowindow,

The issue, first time:

[image]

Rest of the times:

[image]

So I [found out](https://www.google.es/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=bug%20infowindow%20scrollbar) that adding `maxWidth` solved the problem,

For me, it Doesn't; If I set the `maxWidth` to 200px, the scrollbar dissapears, but its smaller than I need,

[image]

If I set 250px (size I need), the scrollbar persists

[image]

Any idea what could I try?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e0x20tvs/3/

```js
$sescam_ventana = {
  init: function() {
    this.mapa();
  },
  mapa: function() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&callback=$sescam_ventana.mapSetup';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  },
  mapSetup: function() {
    var styles = [
      /*
   {
    stylers: [
     { saturation: -100 }
    ]
   },{
    featureType: "road",
    elementType: "geometry",
    stylers: [
     { visibility: "simplified" }
    ]
   },{
    featureType: "poi.business",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
     { visibility: "simplified" }
    ]
   }
  */
    ];
    var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, {
      name: "SESCAM"
    }); //
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 16,
      scrollwheel: false,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.6177074, 4.9725879),
      mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
      }
    }
    var handleMarkerClick = function(marker, index) {
      var $navigationMenu = jQuery('<div>');
      jQuery('.menu-item').each(function(i) {
        var $button = jQuery('<button>');
        $button.text(jQuery(this).text());
        $button.addClass(jQuery(this).data('class'));
        $navigationMenu.append($button);
      });
      if (typeof infowindow === 'undefined') {
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          height: 380
        });
      }
      var centro = infoCentros[index] //helpful data
      infowindow.setContent(
        '<div class="sescam-info-window">' +
        '<h3>' + centro.nombre + '</h3>' +
        '<p>' + centro.lugar + '</h3>' +
        '<p class="titulo">Coordinador</p>' +
        '<p><strong>' + centro.coordinador.nombre + '</strong></p>' +
        '<p><a href="mailto:' + centro.coordinador.email + '">' + centro.coordinador.email + '</a></p>' +
        '<p class="titulo">Responsable</p>' +
        '<p><strong>' + centro.responsable.nombre + '</strong></p>' +
        '<p><a href="mailto:' + centro.responsable.email + '">' + centro.responsable.email + '</a></p>' +
        '<div class="menu">' + $navigationMenu.html() + '</div>' + '</div>'

      );
      infowindow.open(marker.getMap(), marker);
    }
    var handleMenu = function() {
      jQuery('body').on('click', '.menu button', function() {
        var itemClass = jQuery(this).attr('class');
        jQuery('.listado.' + itemClass).stop(true, true).slideDown().siblings('.listado').stop(true, true).slideUp();
      });
    }
    this.gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapa'), mapOptions);
    this.gmap.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
    this.gmap.setMapTypeId('map_style');
    this.mapMarkers = [];
    this.mapInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      height: 380
    });
    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
      $sescam_ventana.gmap.fitBounds($sescam_ventana.mapBounds);
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < this.mapMarkers.length; i++) {
      // primero eliminamos todos los markers que pudiera haber de una visualización anterior
      this.mapMarkers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    this.mapMarkers.length = 0; // reseteamos el array
    this.mapBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var c = 0; // de inicio no sabemos cuantos elementos tienen realmente latitud y longitud, este contador nos lo chivará
    var latlon; // lo guardamos fuera del each para poder verlo después, si resulta que es el único elemeto a mostrar
    for (var i = 0; i < infoCentros.length; i++) {
      var centro = infoCentros[i];
      var lat = centro.cordenadas.lat;
      var lon = centro.cordenadas.long;
      if (lat && lon) {
        c++;
        latlon = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
        var moptions = {
          position: latlon,
          map: $sescam_ventana.gmap
        }
        moptions.icon = 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons-land/vista-map-markers/256/Map-Marker-Marker-Outside-Pink-icon.png';
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(moptions);
        $sescam_ventana.mapMarkers.push(marker);
        //google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', handleMarkerClick);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', handleMarkerClick.bind(undefined, marker, i));

        $sescam_ventana.mapBounds.extend(latlon);
      }
    }
    if (c > 1) {
      $sescam_ventana.gmap.fitBounds(this.mapBounds);
    } else {
      // si solo hay uno el fitbounds no hace un zoom ni un centrado correctos
      $sescam_ventana.gmap.setCenter(latlon);
    }
    handleMenu();
  }
}
jQuery(function() {
  $sescam_ventana.init();
});
```

```css
.gmapa {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
}
#mapa {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gmapa">
  <script>
    var infoCentros = [{
      "nombre": "El nombre 0",
      "texto": "Lorem ipsum sit met hamet amid0",
      "lugar": "Toledo",
      "coordinador": {
        "nombre": "Ana M\u00aa del Mar Alonso Fern\u00e1ndez",
        "email": "anapilar@gmail.com"
      },
      "responsable": {
        "nombre": "Ana M\u00aa del Mar Alonso Fern\u00e1ndez",
        "email": "anapilar@gmail.com"
      },
      "cordenadas": {
        "lat": 39.150544196,
        "long": -4.8019412125
      }
    }, {
      "nombre": "El nombre 1",
      "texto": "Lorem ipsum sit met hamet amid1",
      "lugar": "Toledo",
      "coordinador": {
        "nombre": "Ana M\u00aa del Mar Alonso Fern\u00e1ndez",
        "email": "anapilar@gmail.com"
      },
      "responsable": {
        "nombre": "Ana M\u00aa del Mar Alonso Fern\u00e1ndez",
        "email": "anapilar@gmail.com"
      },
      "cordenadas": {
        "lat": 39.150544196,
        "long": -4.7019412125
      }
    }, {
      "nombre": "El nombre 2",
      "texto": "Lorem ipsum sit met hamet amid2",
      "lugar": "Toledo",
      "coordinador": {
        "nombre": "Ana M\u00aa del Mar Alonso Fern\u00e1ndez",
        "email": "anapilar@gmail.com"
      },
      "responsable": {
        "nombre": "Ana M\u00aa del Mar Alonso Fern\u00e1ndez",
        "email": "anapilar@gmail.com"
      },
      "cordenadas": {
        "lat": 39.150544196,
        "long": -4.6019412125
      }
    }, {
      "nombre": "El nombre 3",
      "texto": "Lorem ipsum sit met hamet amid3",
      "lugar": "Toledo",
      "coordinador": {
        "nombre": "Ana M\u00aa del Mar Alonso Fern\u00e1ndez",
        "email": "anapilar@gmail.com"
      },
      "responsable": {
        "nombre": "Ana M\u00aa del Mar Alonso Fern\u00e1ndez",
        "email": "anapilar@gmail.com"
      },
      "cordenadas": {
        "lat": 39.150544196,
        "long": -4.5019412125
      }
    }, {
      "nombre": "El nombre 4",
      "texto": "Lorem ipsum sit met hamet amid4",
      "lugar": "Toledo",
      "coordinador": {
        "nombre": "Ana M\u00aa del Mar Alonso Fern\u00e1ndez",
        "email": "anapilar@gmail.com"
      },
      "responsable": {
        "nombre": "Ana M\u00aa del Mar Alonso Fern\u00e1ndez",
        "email": "anapilar@gmail.com"
      },
      "cordenadas": {
        "lat": 39.150544196,
        "long": -4.4019412125
      }
    }];
  </script>
  <div id="mapa"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just went through this a few months ago.  FWIW, I believe the issue was caused by a custom font size and going back to default solved it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**

In your specific case, it has to do with the Roboto web font. It is included in the Google Maps API, but nothing is using it at the time on your page before an InfoWindow is opened so the browser has no reason to download it, and doesn't.

When you open the infoWindow, however, the browser at the point realizes it needs the font, and starts to download it, but google maps has measured the infoWindow size before the font is downloaded (see the original answer on how google maps api measures on infoWindow's size). When the font has finished downloading, the content in the infoWindow gets re-painted in the Roboto font which in fact makes the infoWindow a different (larger) size than the size that Google measured it to be before the font was downloaded and it's at this point you'll see scrollbars.

This also explains why you see scrollbars the first time - when google maps measured the infoWindow before the font was downloaded - but you won't see them after - because the font is already downloaded, whatever measurements google maps takes now will be the correct ones.

So, the solution is to

**a)** Render something in the Roboto font on your page (causing the browser to download that font) before the first infoWindow is open OR

**b)** Use a different font (one that is used elsewhere on your page, and thus is downloaded on page load) for your infoWindow content.

I'll leave the rest of my answer up because it's a common misunderstanding of how infoWindows work, and, as you pointed out with your google search, a lot of people got hung up on it.

**TLDR:**

**Never use a parent selector (e.g. like #map-canvas) to style the HTML content of your infoWindow.**

It's not a bug. Here's how google maps info window styles work:

When you tell google maps API that you want to open an infoWindow with HTML content, google dynamically creates a div element, appends it to your body tag, grabs the measurements of the dynamically created div, and then appends a div with those measurements to the map which is your infoWindow.

Here's where the trick comes into play.

Let's say this is your HTML:

```
<div id="map-canvas">
</div>
```

and this is your infoWindow content:

```
<h1>I'm an infoWindow</h1>
<p>Hi there!</p>
```

and here is your CSS:

```
h1 { font-size: 18px; }
#map-canvas h1 { font-size: 24px; }
```

Google will almost always draw this infoWindow incorrectly - because when it dynamically creates infoWindow div and appends it to the body to get the measurements, the div will have an `h1` font-size of 18px. So now google has the measurements and places this div on the map, at which point the `h1` font-size increases to `24px` so now google is using the ***wrong*** measurements and your infoWindow will end up having scrollbars.

I've always found the easiest way to work with infoWindow CSS is to use a wrapper div and always target it, so you're infoWindow HTML content would look like:

```
<div class="info-window-content">
    <h1>I'm an infoWindow</h1>
    <p>Hi there!</p>
</div>
```

And then your CSS could look like:

```
/* global styles */
h1 { font-size: 18px; }
p { line-height: 1.6; }

/* info window styles */
.info-window-content h1 { font-size: 24px; }
.info-window-content p { line-height: 1.2; }
```

and you wouldn't end up with scrollbars in your infoWindow.

Comment: Hi, I am not using Roboto font family, I am using `Avenir` but it is a web font (not from google), the thing is that I Do have a wrapper of my own (if you check out the code); So I am not really sure if you answer applies to my case.. any thoughts?

Comment: I'd need to see your code in the wild - in the case of the jsfiddle that you posted, my answer is correct. I am certain about what the problem is - google is basing it's measurements of your content on something that isn't ready yet on the first info window load, and when it is finally ready, google's measurements are already complete. Are you only using Avenir in your infoWindow?

Comment: Actually I see now the Roboto you mean, but is Google who has it in his stylesheets, I am using Avenir in the whole site... any thoughts?

Comment: Google has this in their maps API stylesheet `.gm-style { font-family: Roboto` that puts the Roboto font-family in their infoWindow's. You have to apply a style more specific than that to override it. E.g. `.info-window-content { font-family: Avenir; }`

Comment: Please, for anybody else reading this comment thread - note that changing the font family **does not** fix the scrollbar issue, but making sure that everything required to render your infowindow content (including fonts) must be already downloaded (with the exception of images, which are handled differently) in order for google maps api to get the correct measurements so that your infowindow may be displayed without scrollbars.

Answer (score -1):

i got some erorr like your one 
i used solution like this

```
.gm-style div div div div {max-width: 250px !important ;}

.sescam-info-window{position: absolute;overflow: hidden}
```

this is my mp view check more use inspect element good luck

http://www.lankabird.com/index.php/virtualtravelagent/map

Answer (score -2):

Edit: okay, what was needed, was the parent of .info-window-content .

So, the only thing I did, was add

```
.gm-style-iw>div {
  overflow: hidden !important; 
}
```

I made a fork of your post. http://jsfiddle.net/mygt82wp/ .
Does that work?

I think this could be a generic solution, for this Google Maps bug, it should work for every infoWindow, I think.

---

Old post:

I think the easiest and most effective thing you can do, is simply 1 line of css:

```
.info-window-content {overflow: hidden}
```

Maybe make that  {overflow: hidden !important} if needed

Comment: Hi, thanks for your anser but this does not work, there is no scrollbar but its even worse because there is not a chance to see the whole content, it gets breaked up... salut